# How do I backup and restore a Moto X to a replacement Moto X? (Apps, icons, and SMS)

Tags: backup, restore, home-screen, home-screen-folders, moto-x

I used the Motorola Migrate utility to copy my data such as SMS, photos, and other stuff to my replacement phone.

What I'm missing is my apps (Google Authenticator) and the data that goes with those apps (all the saved OTP pins in Google Authenticator).

Id also like to keep all the icon positions and not have to re-drag them into the specific places I'm used to.

How do I copy this data to my new phone?

Comment: Did you take a look at our [backup tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/backup/info)? You'll find the solution there. Hint: If you've got a custom recovery, a Nandroid backup should do that (provided hardware is the same). Otherwise, `adb backup` is the one coming closest (provided Android 4.0+ on both devices).

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet would probably be to backup using `adb backup` and restore it to the new device. The command you would use is:

> `adb backup -all -f C:\backup.ab`
>
> Or substitute the path of your choice in place of C:.

The full process and entire list of options (which you could use to backup and restore specific apps and settings, like your homescreen) can be found [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1420351).